# ROS2 Python launch files

Tags: python, ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings. Since ROS2 allows for launch files written in Python I would like to ask if there is a usable/proper documentation available for such files (possible commands, their definition and so on)?

I am hard pressed to find even the syntax for more advanced use cases as the generic ones of the [tutorials](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Launch-Files/Creating-Launch-Files/). Almost all examples are written in XML, however I imagine the things written in XML are also possible in Python.

Such as the usage of a launch file inside of another launch file, the search for ROS2 packages in the workspace, etc.

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/master/launch/doc/source/architecture.rst) on github is not really extensive enough to use the Python launch system properly. Is there maybe a comparison between the XML commands and the Python commands?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372416/ros2-python-launch-files/) by [NotARobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/69326/notarobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2021-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree, this was confusing for me when I made the transition previously.

I think the `ros2_cookbook` might help you in:

- including other launch files
- getting the share directory of the workspace

https://github.com/mikeferguson/ros2_cookbook/blob/main/pages/launch.md

---

Originally posted by [vinny](https://answers.ros.org/users/52902/vinny/) with karma: 291 on 2021-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NotARobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/69326/notarobot/) on 2021-02-23**:
Thank you! That is the information I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most extensive documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/master/launch/doc/source/architecture.rst#id1)

For a few examples, you can see:

[Example with event handler Python launch node](https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/blob/master/launch_ros/examples/lifecycle_pub_sub_launch.py)

[Another example](https://www.theconstructsim.com/ros2-qa-215-how-to-use-ros2-python-launch-files/)

[Launch files for large projects](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Tutorials/Launch/Using-ROS2-Launch-For-Large-Projects.html)

---

Originally posted by [Raza Rizvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/84361/raza-rizvi/) with karma: 95 on 2022-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2